# Properly Merge data between two databases?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two databases `QA` and `Dev`. `Dev` database gets rapid changes by several developers.

I have added a `Settings` table to `DEV` which will keep application settings. Also some table columns were dropped in two other tables and some table column's data types were changed. Now I have a problem on how to Merge `DEV` with `QA`.

1. `QA` has latest data entered by QA testers
2. `QA` has old table structures
3. `DEV` has up to date table structures but old data.

Considering those factors, How do I merge `DEV` to `QA` without corrupting existing QA tables and data in it, especially the data?

Comment: First step is to use a database project to version control the schema and allow you to compare and apply change scripts. But I don't beleive there is any special way to do this. Some changes just need to be applied with hand-built scripts, i.e new columns with new data, schema redesign.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid So my understanding is use Schema compare tool to compare two schemas and manually change QA database to match with Dev?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow below steps, to create database project for DEV and generate changes script against QA.

1. Import existing database(DEV) to database project in SSDT. [More on Importing database in SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/import-into-a-database-project?view=sql-server-ver15). I would suggest you to properly group code properly, as SSMS (my personal preference of grouping code in SSDT)
2. Now, you can use SqlPackage.exe to generate incremental script(using /script parameter) for QA database based on DEV database project generated in step no. 1. [More on SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15#script-parameters-and-properties). Walk through the changes to see whether everything is fine, just to be sure.

**Note**: I would suggest you to automate this process in future, using devops. You can use /Publish option of SqlPackage.exe, for automating the deployment to QA database.